# chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file while installing nagios with SELinux

Tags: linux, centos, selinux, nagios

I'm setting up Nagios core on CentOS with SELINUX=enforcing.

I try to run

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /usr/local/nagios/sbin/
```

as [suggested in the manual](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/quickstart-fedora.html), but I get this error messages:

```
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `cmd.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `trends.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `histogram.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `avail.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `history.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `status.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `tac.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `showlog.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `notifications.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `extinfo.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `statuswml.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `outages.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `statuswrl.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `statusmap.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `config.cgi'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `summary.cgi'
```

Any ideas how to avoid these errors?

Comment: Label the files? i.e. add a user and role label, aside from the type label.

Answer (score 5):

You need to relabel the files with the right selinux type:

```
semanage fcontext -a -s system_u -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /usr/local/nagios/sbin/*
```

Answer (score 1):

10 years ago!
Can you solve the problem?
I also faced the same problem and read almost all the contents of the internet.
My OS is Ubuntu. When I typed the command `ls -lZ`, I realized that none of my files and directories have labels! So, according to [Sergi Lomarkov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12377/sergei-lomakov) answer, I installed semanage and with the command `semange fcontext`, I wanted to create a label on the directory. But I encountered the following error parsing `semanage configuration file: syntax error /n ValueError: Could not create semanage handle`.
And I did not find any solution for it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417431)