# chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp'

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

Whenever I'm trying to execute this line to configure SELinux to install xrdp from [this](https://www.l3pdu.com/2015/12/linux-for-my-son-how-to-install-xrdp-on-centos/) tutorial:

```
# chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp
# chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

I get these errors:

```
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp'
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman'
```

I'm on CentOS 7.2 64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command has to give more information.  It has been discussed before (but I see no *duplicates*).

For example,

- in *[chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file while installing nagios with SELinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23610/chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file-while-installing-nagios-wit)*, Sergei Lomakov pointed out that it was first necessary to label the files using `semanage`.
- in *[Linux chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683510/linux-chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file)*, the suggested solution uses the complete type in the `chcon` command (but you would have to first determine the type using `ls -Z`).  The complete type would usually have a colon (`:`) in the name, because it represents a hierarchy.

For example, `ls -lZ` gives these tags for a sample listing:

```
$ ls -lZ msginit msgmerge msgunfmt
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0   msginit
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0   msgmerge
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0   msgunfmt
```

and `chcon` is expecting something like `unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0` in its argument.  A `bin_t` is only partial information.

The referenced procedure should have worked, and the use of `chcon` redundant.  Checking my CentOS7, I happen to have `xrdp` installed, and a listing shows

```
$ ls -lZ xrdp xrdp-chansrv xrdp-sesman xrdp-sessvc
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       xrdp
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       xrdp-chansrv
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       xrdp-sesman
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       xrdp-sessvc
```

The `system_u` field is the SELinux *user*, the `object_r` field is the *role*, `bin_t` is the *type* and `s0` is the (default) *level*.  The files in `/usr/sbin` get their context from a pattern shown by   `semanage fcontext -l` (but there are a lot of matches).  In following the guide, you may have removed the pattern for the `xrdp` — or even for `/usr/sbin`.  However, you can be more explicit in the command, by specifying the user and role using `chcon`:

```
chcon -u system_u -r object_r --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp
chcon -u system_u -r object_r --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

Alternatively, if the patterns are intact but (for instance) you had moved the files rather than installing them, you could repair things using

```
restorecon -v /usr/sbin/xrdp
restorecon -v /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

Further reading:

- [5.6. SELinux Contexts – Labeling Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html)
- [5.6.2. Persistent Changes: semanage fcontext](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html)
- [**`restorecon`** - restore file(s) default SELinux security contexts.](http://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon)
- [**`chcon`** - change file SELinux security context](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon)

Comment: I still don't get it , Can you tell me what command would be the fix for it then ? as I'm not really familiar with linux Neither SELinux :(

Answer (score 11):

I'm also on CentOS 7, and this works for me:

```
chcon -h system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 /usr/sbin/xrdp
chcon -h system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

Comment: While Thomas gave a pretty comprehensive answer, the solution is not that straightforward. I had to do a lot of try and error till I reached these two commands, which are actually working

Comment: That worked for me too in a CentOs box.

Answer (score 4):

It might help someone, so here is my simple 2 cents. If you somehow disabled selinux, you might face this issue. to resolve this, just change the selinux back to normal.
open 
/etc/selinux/config
and change

SELINUX=disabled

back to

SELINUX=enforcing