# Kali linux: I cannot connect from remote system using xrdp and mstsc

Tags: kali-linux, remote-management

I have some trouble

I want to connect to kali from remote system that is the Windows7 using xrdp and mstsc.

so I installed xrdp service and run, next I tried to connect from windows, 
but it didn't work, and had no error messages.

so I checked /var/log/xrdp.log, and got some clues.

It said that:

```
[20160725-14:03:37] [INFO ] A connection received from: 0.0.0.0 port 9036
[20160725-14:03:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:9036 - socket: 11
[20160725-14:03:37] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 10
[20160725-14:03:37] [CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20160725-14:03:37] [WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be used: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20160725-14:03:37] [DEBUG] xrdp_000014b6_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20160725-14:03:37] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0xe0010412 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20160725-14:03:51] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 16
[20160725-14:03:55] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 16
[20160725-14:03:59] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 16
[20160725-14:04:03] [ERROR] Failure to connect to sesman: 127.0.0.1 port: 3350
[20160725-14:04:03] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 16
[20160725-14:04:03] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 1
[20160725-14:24:56] [INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:9036 - socket: 11
[20160725-14:24:56] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20160725-14:24:56] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
```

and I searched with the keywords "Invalid X.509 certificate path defined" and get some solutions.

[chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274360/chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file-usr-sbin-xrdp)

I tried it, but it also failed:

```
root@kali:~# chcon -u system_u -r object_r --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp'
```

how can I solve this problem?

added

```
root@kali:~# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             default
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? (because you use `chcon`)

Comment: @richard How can I check that?

Comment: You used `chcon`, this indicates that you (or the person advising you) believe that you  have security-enhanced-linux (selinux) enabled, or that you are using the wrong tool. (use `sestatus` to check)

Comment: @richard When I input `sestatus`, the shell returns `-su: sestatus: command not found`.
Is this the selinux not enabled?

Comment: @richard ok,,, I installed selinux package and changed secure context of xrdp, srdp-sesman.
but the errors are unchaned and I still can't connect

Comment: No you have just added the management package (**do NOT enable it**). Add the results of `sestatus` to the question. At this stage I can not tell if this problem is related to selinux or not.

Comment: @richard OK, I appended `sestatus` result. please check and thanks

Comment: From https://www.linux.com/answers/what-selinux-and-how-does-it-work — “The permissive option enables the SELinux code, but causes it to operate in a mode where accesses that would be denied by policy are permitted but audited.”. Therefore your problem is **not** with selinux, and `chcon` will not help you.

Comment: @richard Thanks! Then I should find another way...

Comment: Try connecting to rdp server, from a client on the server (it may give better feedback).

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in `xrdp.log` line:

```
[20160725-14:04:03] [ERROR] Failure to connect to sesman: 127.0.0.1 port: 3350
```

try starting the service xrdp-sesman using one of the following methods:

```
$ service xrdp-sesman start
```

or

```
$ systemctl start xrdp-sesman
```