# chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file

Tags: rhel, selinux

I get the following when trying to allow `httpd` to write to application specific directories.

```
[xxx MISP]# chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/MISP/app/files
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘/var/www/MISP/app/files’
```

Comment: What does ls -lZ var/www/MISP/app/files return?

Comment: -rw-r----- root   apache ?                                empty
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                feed-metadata
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                misp-galaxy
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                misp-objects
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                scripts
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                taxonomies
drwxr-x--- apache apache ?                                terms
drwxr-x--- root   apache ?                                warninglists

Comment: Yes, but what are the selinux contexts associated with the listing (hence the -Z flag)

Comment: I used the Z flag, but it didn't pull back anything additional.

Comment: Do you actually have selinux enabled and running on the system?

Comment: Ha! That's a good reason why the command wouldn't be working! Doh! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some rule with `semanage` for your app/files directory, and then apply with `restorecon -Rv`.

See detailed explanations in this article (especially section about using `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`): [Configuring SELinux Policies for Apache Web Servers](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/)

Answer (score 0):

According other threads here on Unix Stackexchange: "[chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/usr/sbin/xrdp'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274360/chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file-usr-sbin-xrdp)" or "[chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file while installing nagios with SELinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23610/chcon-cant-apply-partial-context-to-unlabeled-file-while-installing-nagios-wit)", it seems that it is necessary to label the files using `semanage` and if there is SELinux in enforcing mode.